# How to call msbuild from a batch file from msbuild from team build?

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

I'm using Team Build (2010) to call an msbuild script with an Exec task that calls a batch file that in turn calls msbuild. Like this:

```
<Exec Command="BatchFileThatCallsMSBuild.bat" />
```

Of course the batch file does a bunch of other junk or I'd just use the MSBuild task.

The problem is that when the batch file tries to call msbuild it can't find it.

```
'msbuild' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

How do I get the necessary environment set up in the exec task?

I tried changing the command to:

```
<Exec Command="%22$(VS100COMNTOOLS)..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat%22&amp;BatchFileThatCallsMSBuild.bat" />
```

but no dice, still msbuild is not found.

Comment: Are you specifying the full path to the msbuild executable in the batch file, or are you relying on a relative path (which isn't guaranteed to be what you expect it to be)?

Comment: The batch file calls "msbuild" unadorned.

Comment: Try specifying the full path to msbuild.exe.  I'm not on a dev pc (actually, I'm on a PC that I just reinstalled Windows on a few hours ago) so I can't look up the full path for you, but it should be in %Windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\(Framework version)\

Comment: I'm getting the batch file from a third party submission so I can't tweak it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer I came up with was to take advantage of the seldom-demonstrated-online multi-line Command string to the Exec task.

```
<Exec Command="call &quot;%VS100COMNTOOLS%..\..\VC\vcvarsall.bat&quot; x86
    set AnotherEnvVar=$(RandomMSBuildProperty)
    call BatchFileThatCallsMSBuild.bat
    type file_with_output_from_the_msbuilds_in_the_batchfile.log" />
```

This let me set up the basic build environment (call to vcvarsall), push an msbuild property out to the Exec's environment where the batched msbuilds could see it, call the batch file, and even pull the hidden msbuild output up to the level of the Exec task for clearer logging in Team Build.

I'm not thrilled with having to embed yet another reference to this specific VS version in my code, but it works for now.